# Runtime error - java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String

Tags: java

I have written this code for image analysis:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ImageAnalysis {

    private double[][] filter;
    private double[][] Im;
    private int k;
    private int n;
    private int m;

    public ImageAnalysis(String filename) {

        BufferedReader br = null;

        try {

            String sCurrentLine;

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
            sCurrentLine = br.readLine();
            String[] val = sCurrentLine.split(" ");
            // extracting the row and column from file first line
            int row = Integer.parseInt(val[0]);
            int col = Integer.parseInt(val[1]);

            n = row;
            m = col;

            Im = new double[row][col];
            int i = 0;
            // reading the file line by line
            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                val = sCurrentLine.split(" ");
                // System.out.println(val.length+" "+i);
                // store the values into two dimensional array
                for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
                    Im[i][j] = Double.parseDouble(val[j]);
                }
                i++;
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (br != null)
                    br.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        /*
         * 
         * filter[0][0]=0; filter[0][1]=-1/8; filter[0][2]=0;
         * 
         * filter[1][0]=-1/8; filter[1][1]=1/2; filter[1][2]=-1/8;
         * 
         * filter[2][0]=0; filter[2][1]=-1/8; filter[2][2]=0;
         */

    }

    // this method will apply filter on image file
    public double[][] runFilter(String filterfilename) {
        BufferedReader br = null;

        try {

            String sCurrentLine;

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filterfilename));
            sCurrentLine = br.readLine();
            String[] val = sCurrentLine.split(" ");
            // extracting k value from file first line
            k = Integer.parseInt(val[0]);
            // applying the formula 2*k+1 to calculate row and col of matrix
            int row = 2 * k + 1, col = 2 * k + 1;
            // make array
            filter = new double[row][col];
            int i = 0;
            // reading the file line by line
            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                val = sCurrentLine.split(" ");
                for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
                    filter[i][j] = Double.parseDouble(val[j]);
                }
                i++;
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (br != null)
                    br.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        // calculate the row and col for filtered image
        int row = n - 2 * k;
        int col = m - 2 * k;
        // make filtered image 2D array
        double[][] filteredImage = new double[row][col];
        // filled the vvalue in filtered array by applying formula
        for (int a = 0; a < row; a++) {
            for (int b = 0; b < col; b++) {
                double sum = 0;
                for (int i = -k; i <= k; i++) {
                    for (int j = -k; j <= k; j++) {
                        sum += filter[i + k][j + k] * Im[a + i + k][b + j + k];
                    }
                }
                filteredImage[a][b] = sum;
                // System.out.println(sum);
            }
        }
        return filteredImage;
    }

}
```

It seems to work fine with .ftr files, but when I try with .ipi, I get the following runtime error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842)
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
at assignment2.ImageAnalysis.<init>(ImageAnalysis.java:44)
at ImageAnalysis_test_visible_04.main(ImageAnalysis_test_visible_04.java:3)
```

The .ipi file is:

```
18 20
1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
-1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0
-1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0
-1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0
-1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0
-1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0
-1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0
-1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0
-1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0
-1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0
```

The program uses real values between -1 and 1 where -1 means "no light at all" = black, 0 corresponds to 50% gray and 1 is white.

Comment: Did you check if .ipi file is properly splitted and val has some values?

Comment: Yes, there's nothing wrong with the .ipi file.

Comment: Which line is line 44?

Comment: The closing curly bracket under

    filter[i][j] = Double.parseDouble(val[j]);

Comment: Will suggest to delete the post now as well because the your updated question doesn't make any sense now and no longer helpful for others :)

Comment: Editing does not delete anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your while loop I would do

```
val = sCurrentLine.split("\\s+");
```

just in case there are more than one spaces

Comment: Thank you. It works now with both .ftr and .ipi files.

Comment: Note that getting an Empty string could actually mean that the regular expression (the split method is regular-expression based) matched two consecutive spaces, so in between of them is an Empty string